# Find the PYTHONPATH/env bitnami uses and how to use it

Tags: python, django, bitnami

I've setup the one-click install of bitnami on Google Cloud. It's got Django 2.0 installed and that only works with python 3.x shown when I get out of a virtualenv I've created

```
(djangoenv) bitnami@britecore-vm:/home/muiruri_samuel/apps/django$ cd ..
(djangoenv) bitnami@britecore-vm:/home/muiruri_samuel/apps$ deactivate
bitnami@britecore-vm:/home/muiruri_samuel/apps$ . /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh
bitnami@britecore-vm:/home/muiruri_samuel/apps$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
ImportError: No module named site
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 5 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
bitnami@britecore-vm:/home/muiruri_samuel/apps$ python
ImportError: No module named site
```

I tried a snippet I saw on bitnami community on starting the env but it didn't work. I need to pip install a new package to where bitnami has it's packages so it can use it. I'm ok with just running my commands thereafter from the other virtualenv just incase it shows that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Him I think the problem is that when you type **"python"**, you're using the Python installed on the system (`/usr/bin/python`). However, when you type **"python3"** you will be using included on the stack (`/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python3`). You can check it by running:

`which python
which python3`

Comment: likely but I delete the instance and went with a fresh install, useful just in case someone else gets to the same issue.